# how can i use isnull and inbetween functions in mysql together for a date

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have a table in mysql with two columns start date and end date. and i have a search option where i can input the dates and search for it. the textbox could be empty so i have used the isnull function.right now the functionality which i have implemented is that we have to enter the exact start date and end date then only the value would be returned.I would like to return the data which falls between the start date and enddate

following is the code in the stored procedure.

```
 FROM Promo_ODM_ShipWithout
WHERE
 StartDate LIKE  ISNULL(@StartDate,StartDate) 
                AND ISNULL(EndDate,-1) Like ISNULL(ISNULL(@EndDate,EndDate)  ,-1) 
                AND  SKUCode Like ISNULL(@SkuCode,SKUCode)

                 ORDER BY Id
                    )RowSet
         WHERE ROW_NUM >@LeftStart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  Promo_ODM_ShipWithout
WHERE
(
  @StartDate IS NULL OR EndDate >= @StartDate
)
AND
(
  @EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate <= @EndDate 
)
```

Comment: this solution is not working if i am giving start date as 10/29/2012 and end date as 10/30/2012 then also date with starting date 10/01/2012.

Comment: if i am giving start date as 10/01/2012 and end date as 10/11/2012 then also date with starting date 10/31/2012 data having start date 10/09/2012 and 10/10/2012 is also returned.